# Microsoft Login screen does not show properly

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms, uwp, azure-active-directory

We are getting the below Microsoft Login screen:
[image]

We are using Microsoft Azure Active Directory to secure login in our UWP application. We are using the `AuthenticationContext` class to retrieve authentication tokens.
We are using the version "3.19.4.11002"of the library *Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory*.

Comment: Can you check the Internet Explorer options? It is probably set to secure mode or deny CSS/Javascript

Comment: We are working with Xamarin UWP application.

Comment: It looks web not xamarin uwp??

Comment: Kinda looks like it is failing to load the CSS on the login page and is not related to ADAL in anyway. This is either a network issue or a problem on the MS end.

Comment: We are using Azure Active directory in our UWP application to authenticate.

Comment: What's the result if you direct access the login page in explorer?  According to https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/azureadb2c/2018/03/28/issue-mitigated-login-page-not-displaying-properly-in-australia/ ,are you in Australia? Please try to use Fiddler tool to catch the http requests to see if there're any 404 error. You need to narrow down your issue.